# Does the same account need to be used to publish app?

Tags: google-play, publishing, google-play-console

I am using a gmail account for the services and APIs in a flutter app like firebase, youtube api. Do I need to use the same gmail id to publish the app or can I use a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to use the same account for publishing the app. There is no such relation between the account used for APIs and services to the account used for publishing the app on play store.